# Как найти список часто употребляемых глаголов с данным существительным

Tags: глаголы, словосочетания, существительные

Для каждого существительного есть свои глаголы, которые нередко употребляются вместе с ним. Есть ли какой-нибудь сайт, которые помогает найти подобный набор глаголов для данного слова?

Я искал в гугле, но ни на что не наткнулся.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я обычно проверяю сочетаемость в Яндексе. Например, есть существительное "счастье". Добавляете слово "сочетаемость" — и получаете ответ для всех частей речи.

[https://kartaslov.ru/сочетаемость-слова/счастье](https://kartaslov.ru/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%B5)

Comment: Спасибо! Отличный сайт kartaslov.ru.

Answer (score 3):

Словари сочетаемости слов
Цель словарей сочетаемости – показать, как правильно подбирать слова, чтобы обеспечить их соответствие друг другу в смысловом и стилистическом отношениях.

Денисов П. Н., Морковкин В. В., Новиков Л. А. Проспект учебного словаря сочетаемости слов русского языка. М., 1971.

Пособие по лексической сочетаемости слов русского языка. Словарь-справочник / Сост. Т. И. Анисимова, З. Э. Иванова, Р. В. Ульянко; Под ред. Т. П. Плещенко и Л. Ф. Саковец. Минск, 1975. (Пособие для студентов-иностранцев и учащихся национальных школ.)

Словарь сочетаемости слов русского языка / Под ред. П. Н. Денисова, В. В. Морковкина. М., 1978; 2-е изд., испр. и доп. М., 1983; 3-е изд., испр. М., 2002. (Словарь является наиболее полным лексикографическим описанием сочетаемости слов в нашем языке и представляет собой типичный образец такого словарного издания. В нем собран и обобщен ценный материал о сочетаемости слов по всем трем видам синтаксической связи – согласованию, управлению и примыканию. В словаре около 2500 словарных статей; в качестве заголовочного слова выступают имя существительное, прилагательное, глагол. К слову даются толкование его значений, краткая грамматическая характеристика.)

Регинина К. В., Тюрина Г. П., Широкова Л. И. Устойчивые словосочетания русского языка: Учеб. пос. для студентов-иностранцев / Под ред. Л. И. Широковой М., 1980.

Абдуллаев Ф. М. Опорный словарь сочетаемости слов при образовании русских словосочетаний: Пос. для учителей начальной школы. Баку, 1980.

Красных В. И. Русские глаголы и предикативы. Словарь сочетаемости. М., 1993.

Русские глагольные предложения: Экспериментальный синтаксический словарь / Под общ. ред. Л. Г. Бабенко. М., 2002. В словаре впервые в русской лексикографии систематизированы семантические модели русских глагольных предложений, отражающие все типовые ситуации процессуально-событийного мира.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ!